# Cookies doesnt showup in Firefox with $_COOKIE but visible in firebug and works on other Browsers

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, mozilla

Im using `wordpress` and I set cookies on a purpose which works perfectly on **Chrome and other browsers,** but not in Firefox, `$_COOKIE` is empty when I print it in **firefox**, but contains cookies actually, the same code prints the cookies on other browsers, and of course cookies are visible in Firefox firebug, but not on `$_COOKIE`.

can some one tell me how to access them? what is restricting? how to solve it?
 My code goes this way

```
if(isset($_GET['attr'])){
    $inTwoMonths = 60 * 60 * 24 * 60 + time();
    $attr = $_GET['attr'];
    setcookie('attr', $attr , $inTwoMonths,'/');
    print_r($_COOKIE);
}
```

Comment: `Common Pitfalls: Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires.`

Answer (score 2):

setcookie() only prepares a Cookie header for the response but it will not actually set the value in $_COOKIE. $_COOKIE will have the new value after the next request when it receives the updated cookie data from the client. See http://php.net/setcookie . In your code, you will have to do this:

```
setcookie('attr', $attr , $inTwoMonths,'/');
$_COOKIE['attr'] = $attr;
```

in order for the value in the cookie to be available in the same request.

Comment: ah, not sure, I use to set with the setcookie function alone, but anyways cookies are set, I can see them on the net tab of debugger, only thing is they are not accessible, generally as we logged in we do have some other cookies as well, so they get printed on Chrome but not on other browsers.

Comment: What do you mean they are not accessible? You mean set in $_COOKIE?